# Validating XML schema in java with prefix

Tags: xml, validation

I have an xml message below

```
<web:Add xmlns:web="http://my/web/">
<web:a>1</web:a>
<web:b>2</web:b>
</web:Add>
```

Here is my schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
 <s:element name="Add">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="a" type="s:int" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="b" type="s:int" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
</s:schema>
```

Here is my code

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
File f = new File("C:\\temp\\my.xsd");
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(f);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
Document requestDoc = getDocumentFromString(request,true);
validator.validate(new DOMSource(requestDoc));
```

Why does this fails with 
**cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'web:a'. One of '{a}' is expected.**

if I modify the message and take the prefix oul for the elements like this

```
<web:Add xmlns:web="http://my/web/">
<a>1</a>
<b>2</b>
</web:Add>
```

Then everything works. Why? both messages are valid xml for the schema provided.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `targetNamespace` and `elementFormDefault` attributes of the schema element.

Comment: thanks. That was it! I added the following and it fixed it elementFormDefault="qualified"

Comment: Glad to help.  It's customary on SO to "accept" the best answer to your question by clicking the check mark to the left.